# Font not showing correctly in webView in some Samsung phone

Tags: android, webview, fonts

I'm loading data in webview from my web server.

In some webpages, it contains `Bangali (Bangla) Font`. In most of the devices, everything is working fine.
But some of `Samsung` devices the font is not showing correctly.

```
Galaxy S Duos3 
Galaxy S Duos3 (vivalto3gvn)
Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100)
Galaxy Young2
Galaxy Core (arubaslim)

(Sony)
Xperia acro S (LT26w)
Xperia Z2 (D6503)
```

are some of them.
The actual content should be like

[image]

but the devices are showing like this

[image]

My code is:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, url, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I've checked the answers [Android WebView with garbled UTF-8 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters), [String Encoding problem in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412763/string-encoding-problem-in-webview) and the  [blog post](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-using-custom-ttf-fonts-in-webview/)

can't figure out my problem.

Comment: Maye be you have the wrong encoding name?

Comment: looks like a classic encoding mismatch. Are you making sure *everything* is set to do things in UTF8? (your classes, your resource files, your data read in and write out, etc. etc.)

Comment: It seems everything are in `UTF8`.