# Bug in recently Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Does anybody have similar problem when using a WebView to render app's content? It seem that '#' is not working well in recently update.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String html = "<html><body>This is a #test</body></html>";
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
 }
}
```

Showing "Test is a" (without test) in the recently updated device. If you run this in the emulator you may not see the problem.

Emulator:

[image]

Device:

[image]

Comment: Try this `webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: and also for me in Marshmallow Device your code is working fine [check the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNKSD.png)

Comment: @NileshRathod Cloud you please update all apps from Play Store and try again? I found this problem after updating a few hour ago.

Comment: `Cloud you please update all apps from Play Store` which apps

Comment: Uninstall latest update of Google Chrome App (29 Jan 2019) resolve the problem. Confirm by reinstall the update makes this issue occurs.

Comment: I found something. and i wrote it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486261/1928396

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. From document it said...

> the data is base64 or URL encoded

So the html can not be just a simple string. It should be encoded with base64 like this

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
String html = "<html><body>This is a #test</body></html>";
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(html.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
webView.loadData(base64, "text/html", "base64");
```

Then it is working fine. It used to work fine without encoding in the earlier Chrome version.